# What causes this error Access denied finding property "ro.hardware.chipname"?

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio, bitmap

I'm trying to convert a JSON back to an Object when this error occurs. How can i get rid of this error?
This is the class whose object i'm trying to get after converting from JSON:

```
class Recognition implements Serializable {

    private final String id;
    private final String title;
    private final Float distance;
    private Object extra;
    private RectF location;
    private Integer color;
    private Bitmap crop;

    public Recognition(
            final String id, final String title, final Float distance, final RectF location) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.distance = distance;
        this.location = location;
        this.color = null;
        this.extra = null;
        this.crop = null;
    }

    public void setExtra(Object extra) {
        this.extra = extra;
    }

    public Object getExtra() {
        return this.extra;
    }

    public void setColor(Integer color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public Float getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }

    public RectF getLocation() {
        return new RectF(location);
    }

    public void setLocation(RectF location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public Integer getColor() {
        return this.color;
    }

    public void setCrop(Bitmap crop) {
        this.crop = crop;
    }

    public Bitmap getCrop() {
        return this.crop;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String resultString = "";
        if (id != null) {
            resultString += "[" + id + "] ";
        }

        if (title != null) {
            resultString += title + " ";
        }

        if (distance != null) {
            resultString += String.format("(%.1f%%) ", distance * 100.0f);
        }

        if (location != null) {
            resultString += location + " ";
        }

        if (color != null) {
            resultString += color + " ";
        }

        if (extra != null) {
            resultString += extra + " ";
        }

        if (crop != null) {
            resultString += encodeToBase64(crop, Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100) + " ";
        }

        return resultString.trim();
    }

    public static String encodeToBase64(Bitmap image, Bitmap.CompressFormat compressFormat, int quality)
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOS = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        image.compress(compressFormat, quality, byteArrayOS);
        return Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayOS.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
    }

    public static Bitmap decodeBase64(String input)
    {
        byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decode(input, 0);
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedBytes, 0, decodedBytes.length);
    }

    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        crop.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
        out.writeInt(byteArray.length);
        out.write(byteArray);
    }

    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        int bufferLength = in.readInt();
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[bufferLength];
        int pos = 0;
        do {
            int read = in.read(byteArray, pos, bufferLength - pos);
            if (read != -1) {
                pos += read;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        } while (pos < bufferLength);
        crop = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, bufferLength);
    }
}
```

What I think is that there might be some issue in the constructor or in conversion of bitmap. But i'm not sure. So if you hava any solution. Please let me know.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? @HuzaifaAsif